Why MySQL repeatable read doesn't raise serialization error
I'm looking at MySQL MVCC, and it has strange behavior at Repeatable Read isolation:

Regular SELECT returns the version from the snapshot
SELECT FOR SHARE returns the latest version of the record

Which is probably the least expected behavior. I'm curious about the underlying reason. Postgres has a very simple fix for this - raise an error. So:

If you never run an operation that require exclusive locks (SELECT FOR SHARE or FOR UPDATE, UPDATE, DELETE), then you always see the snapshot version (like in MySQL).
If you do run one of the operations that can't use the older version, then you get an error. And we have to repeat the whole tx.

Is there some technical difficulty that didn't allow MySQL check that there's a new version? I suppose not, so there must be some other reasoning.

This is due to the way InnoDB implements MVCC.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/innodb-locking-reads.html says:

(Old versions of a record cannot be locked; they are reconstructed by applying undo logs on an in-memory copy of the record.)

This means any locking DML statement locks only the most recent committed row of an InnoDB table.
This includes SELECT ... FOR UPDATE, SELECT ... FOR SHARE, UPDATE, DELETE, REPLACE, or even SELECT statements that are executed in assignments, or in subqueries, or by triggers as part of the other locking statements. I'm sure there are other cases of locking statements that I didn't list here.

Yes, but once the lock is released due to a commit, it would make sense to abort current tx. What's the point of reading the last version if that version isn't in the snapshot (read view)? I can't see benefits of working with the last version vs raising an error.

Well, the benefit is that you don't get an error. The query you requested is allowed to go through, possibly after waiting for the other transaction to commit. It's a different strategy than PostgreSQL, but equally valid. I'm sure some users of PostgreSQL say, "Why do I get an error? There's nothing wrong with my query. It should just proceed, and avoid phantom updates by locking the most recent version of the row."

Read Committed allows to have non-repeatable results. And the way it works in MySQL makes sense to me. Now, Repeatable Read in theory should be more consistent. But it's the opposite in MySQL - we can run a query, see new results, and then run another query and see the old results. Even if nothing changed! This looks even less consistent than Read Committed. To me this doesn't make sense, it feels like there's some other reason, some architectural limitation that they ran into. I can't justify such behavior.

And to be on the same page.. PG also locks the records when both transactions modify the same row. The difference is in the outcomes, when the other tx releases the lock by committing. At Read Committed you get your tuple overwritten by the 2nd tx (same as in MySQL). But at Repeatable Read we can't afford 2 statements see different results - that's why PG raises an error. And it feels like MySQL technically should be able to do the same.

Whether it makes sense to you or not, it was a compromise they made consciously. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html: "REPEATABLE READ ... if you issue several plain (nonlocking) SELECT statements within the same transaction, these SELECT statements are consistent also with respect to each other."

I've also seen the behavior similar to PostgreSQL in a product called InterBase, later forked as the open-source product Firebird. You can execute, an update against a row locked by another session. You wait. If the other session rolls back, your update goes through. If the other session commits, you get an error. This was frustrating and confusing to users for the reason that they don't like an update they thought was valid to wait for an indeterminate amount of time, and then get an error. But it's the only way to implement MVCC and maintain RR semantics.
